Question out of scope on two Stack Exchange sites. Where should I have asked it instead?
I posted the same question on two different Stack Exchange network sites - the only ones I thought were relevant. However, on each site I was effectively redirected to the other one.The questions are:

Medical Science SE: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/33974/what-determines-the-rates-of-circumcision-in-each-us-state (since deleted).
Politics SE: What determines the rates of circumcision in each US state?

On the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange site it was too much based in politics:

This question has nothing to do with medical science. The answers aren't going to be science but rather cultural or political, and probably mostly just opinion.

On the Politics Stack Exchange site it was too much based in public health:

Yes, there's a line between questions with a clear public health link, and questions that might happen to be affected by public policy. This is as on-topic as asking which factors influence cancer rates or sunscreen use, i.e. not very.

Where should it be asked? On a third network site? As far as I can see, there isn't any "sociology" Stack Exchange site or any other site that would be relevant. Is that the case?

You may have to accept that some questions don't have an appropriate site.

If you suspect the answer is related to Christianity then you could try [Christianity.SE].

A site about knowledge that puts bureaucracy of questions perfectly fitting into discrete categories before the knowledge of the question is more about categorisation than it is about knowledge.

You can always propose a new site if there's a gap to fall through that needs filling. See: How can I propose a new site? Though, check area 51 first to see if it's already in progress.

Why is this being downvoted? The OP is perfectly polite and asking a reasonable question. "Where would this Q be on scope" is a common question and absolutely on topic here.

@W.O. although your comment is of course factually correct, it seems impractical (to say the least) to suggest starting a new site for a question that is at the crossroads of existing topics - and should therefore IMO be on-topic on at least one of Medical Sciences, Politics, and Christianity, if not all.

Fair to say, but the idea of a sociology stack has been mentioned numerous times. Perhaps there's the momentum now (or shall be at some point) for sufficient numbers to engage in that. As to the question - on-topicness will depend to a great extent on the way it's formulated. I can confirm that when I read it on medical sciences it was formulated in a way that was almost entirely off-topic. @Marijn It had nothing to do with the procedure or criteria/benefits/contraindications for circumcision.

Cont.: I'd urge the OP to try and isolate out the aspects that may be on-topic on a particular site and ask there. They'd need greater familiarity with the network to do that effectively, or a set of sandboxes where there are none at present.

If you can tell me which site to post it on, I can reformulate the question, but the question has several different aspects. Circumcision is unique to American Christianity more than any other country's christianity and it happens across branches (catholicism, mainline protestantism, evangelicalism, etc). It is also subsidised by certain states' medicaid programs. I would like an answer that acknowledges both aspects.
Is there a site that be able to do that?

It's hard to imagine what you expect a proper answer to the question to look like, honestly. Should it be confirming or refuting your suspicions as to what factors influence the result? Looking for more patterns? Showing the result of a principle component analysis on some defined set of factors? Something else?

Reposted on medical - seems to now pass muster.

What W.O. points out is that you might have to break up the question into several parts - especially since, as you say, "the question has several different aspects" - and ask those on appropriate sites (and as for your earlier comment: that "bureaucracy" is there for a reason, and is usually the product of great deliberation of the community, and can, even so, still be discussed on a community's meta site. Yes, knowledge should be valued above categorization, but that's an extremely blurry starting point, since that might suggest everyone can just dump anything there in the name of knowledge.)

As far as I can see, that question probably is not on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.  There are lots of questions people might have that aren't suitable anywhere on any Stack Exchange site.
The Stack Exchange network is not envisioned as a universal source of all knowledge on all topics.  Rather, there are specific sites that each have their own specific scope, based on the decisions of the community that is active at that site.
If you refer to the guidance on the site-recommendation tag, you will see it provides this information:

Not all types of questions belong on a Q&A site, and not everything can find a home here at Stack Exchange.
Do some research before asking. It's often helpful to go to https://stackexchange.com, enter some terms in the search bar in the upper-right, check out the sites that show up in the results, and read their help pages. The full list of sites is also available at https://stackexchange.com/sites

Asking for a list of all major factors that affect something is likely too broad to be a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.  SE sites are envisioned as a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge, and that requires questions of a particular sort (clearly articulated, narrowly focused, answerable in a few paragraphs, criteria for judging answers are clear, etc.)

https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/33975/30145
Well. I have rephrased it, essentially asking the same question, and now it apparently is acceptable, and within the scope of medical sciences stack exchange.
